# In SSMS can I automate the creation of sessions?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Is it possible to have T-SQL code in one session open new sessions and have code run in those other sessions?  I'm still a noob with MS SQL and I'm looking for ways to simulate multiple sessions running, in order to observe locking and blocking and resource contention and CPU usage and all that.
Instead of doing it all manually it would be nice to automate it and be able to specify how many other sessions to open and what code to run in them.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware on how to do this directly on SSMS. Maybe creating multiple connections to the same instance on the Registered Servers and then running the group.
However, there are several 3rd party applications that could help you with that. Here are 2 options:

- SQLQueryStress (with explanation from Brent Ozar)
  https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/05/how-to-fake-load-tests-with-sqlquerystress/
- OStress (article from SQL Shack)
  https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-stress-testing-using-ostress/

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a native way to do this in SSMS. You could do this with SSMS Boost (https://www.ssmsboost.com/) using workspaces or Redgate SQL Test (https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-test/index). there are probably other tools as well, but those are the two I've used before.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to open a temporary new session enabling SQL CMD Mode in SSMS via menu ->Query->SQL CMD Mode:

```
:CONNECT (local)
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT        SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') AS ServerName
                ,SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS ProductVersion
                ,SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel') AS ProductLevel
                ,SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS Edition
                ,SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') AS EngineEdition;
GO
:CONNECT SQLServer1
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT        SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') AS ServerName
                ,SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS ProductVersion
                ,SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel') AS ProductLevel
                ,SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS Edition
                ,SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') AS EngineEdition
GO
```

In this way, you can switch a context. However, there still no way to initiate few parallel outgoing sessions from the same source session using T-SQL. You can do it via external tools